# An algebraic invariant measuring when Leray-Hirsch fails

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I have the following question about the Leray-Hirsch theorem, as stated in Bott&Tu:

Let $E$ be a fiber bundle with fiber $F$ over a manifold $M$ which admits a finite good cover. Assume there exist $e_{1} , ... , e_{n} \in H^{*} (E) $ which satisfy $\forall x,  Sp(i^{*}_{x} e_{1} , ..., i^{*}_{x} e_{n} ) = H^{*} (F_{x} ) $, where $i_{x}: F_{x} \to E$ is the inclusion of the fiber $F$ over the point $x \in M$. Then $H^{*} (E) \cong H^{*} (F) \otimes H^{*} (M) $ via the map $(\alpha \otimes \beta) \mapsto s(\alpha)\cup \pi^{*} \beta$, where $s(\alpha) = \sum_{i} \lambda_{i} e_{i}$ is the unique form which pulls back to $\alpha$ over some arbitrary fixed point $x$.

(Perhaps i've been not-careful in quoting this, but that's beside the point). I am interested in knowing whether or not there exists either a property of $H^{*} (E)$ or a cohomology class in it, which measure whether or not such forms $e_{i}$ exist. To me, it seems like whether or not a ring $R$ decomposes as a tensor product of 2 smaller rings can be answered in a purely algebraic manner, without any topological considerations. Since I don't know a lot of algebra I was wondering if anyone has some nice thoughts on this.

Comment: Perhaps the cokernel of the pullback map on cohomology would work. But that would kind of be a tautology at best.

Comment: Important note: the Leray-Hirsch theorem is not a statement about rings but rather modules over $H^*(M)$.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer I feel like a statement about the image of the pullback on cohomology would still be more topological in nature, which isn't what I want.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Sure, but a lot of rings are modules over a lot of other rings, so I feel like it could be that  $H^{*} (E)$ has the structure of a module over $H^{*} (M)$ without decomposing as a tensor product. All im wondering is if there is a purely algebraic way to measure whether or not this happens, which hopefully could have a differential-topology interpretation